# pm2 running in docker transpiler not working

Tags: node.js, express, docker, pm2

Thank you for taking the time to help me work this out.

- Introduction

I have created a docker and I have also configured a configuration file for pm2. I want to be able to start the docker in development mode and use pm2 inside, be able to debug the typescript through dev tools etc.

The application is built using nodejs, expressjs in typescript.

- Problem
  Running `pm2 start server-debug.config.js` locally everything works fine. I am able to debug the application through Dev tools, I am able to open typescript files and add breakpoints.

When building the docker, everything works fine as well with one exception. When opening the dev tools, I am only able to see the js files, can't debug the typescript.

So basically the transpiler works locally but not remotely through a docker.

- Configuration

  1. Docker file

```

```
# specify the node base image with your desired version node:<version>
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine

# client backend
COPY . /home/api
WORKDIR /home/api

ARG API_TAG
ARG NODE_ENV
ARG CONTAINER_USER
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

RUN npm install && npm install pm2 -g && pm2 install typescript

# Set user to node on production
USER $CONTAINER_USER

# start backend & frontend
ENTRYPOINT if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ];\
then pm2-runtime /home/api/server-dev.config.js --env ${NODE_ENV} --no- 
daemon;\
else pm2-runtime /home/api/server.config.js --env ${NODE_ENV} --no-daemon;\
fi
```

2. Pm2 config file

```

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const serverConfig = require('./server.config');

const devServerConfig = {apps: []};

devServerConfig.apps[0] = _.merge(serverConfig.apps[0], {
    watch: true,
    port: 8000,
    source_map_support: true,
    script: "./dist/App.js",
    ignore_watch: ["data",
    "node_modules",
    "DockerFile",
    ".gitignore",
    "docker-compose*",
    "README.md",
    "server.config.js",
    "logs",
    "server-dev.config.js"],
    node_args: [ "--inspect=0.0.0.0:5858", "--harmony" ],
    error_file : "./logs/error.service-debug.log",
    out_file : "./logs/out.service-debug.log",
    pid_file : "./logs/debug.service.pid",
    log_date_format: "",
    watch_options: {
        "usePolling": true,
        "alwaysStat": true,
        "useFsEvents": false,
    },
})

// , "--require=ts-node/register", "--harmony"

module.exports = devServerConfig;
```

```

3. .env file

   API_TAG=v1.0
   NODE_ENV=development
   CONTAINER_USER=root
   PORT=8000
   MONGO_PORT=27017
4. tsconfig

```

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts",
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
    ]
 }
```

```

Comment: `--no-daemon` not needed for `pm2-runtime`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this issue, after hours of debugging, trial and error, I have found a solution that worked. Adding inline source map inside tsconfig file will solve the issue.

I will accept my own answer as the solution to help others with this issue.